# Getting Images from An Array in Next JS

Tags: arrays, image, next.js, vite

I'm converting a Vite JS project to a Next JS project. In Vite JS, images are imported into the index.js file in the assest folder. And these images are called in an array in the constants/index.js file. In my Next JS project, when I try to call the images in these arrays according to their index numbers in the Image component, I can't get any results. But if I want to use the images in the array in the Image component in my project, I can get results. But this is a time consuming process in my opinion. Is there an easier way?

```
// assets/index.js
import image1 from "./image1.png"
import image2 from "./image2.png"
import image3 from "./image3.png"
export {image1,image2,image3};
```

```
// constants/index.js
import {image1,image2,image3} from "../assets;

export const myArray = [
  {
    title: "Image 1",
    image: image1,
  },
  {
    title: "Image 2",
    image: image2,
  },
  {
    title: "Image 3",
    image: <Image src={image3} alt="Image" width={100} height={100}/>,
  }
];

// The image1 and image2 contents are not displaying in my project. But image3 content can be displayed this way.
```

```
// Usage in a component file.

import { myArray} from "../constants";

<div>
          <img
            src={myArray.image}
            alt={myArray.title}
          />
</div>

// While the image content is not visible, the title content is visible on the browser.
```

Answer (score 0):

Use javascript map funtion

```
{myArray.map((item)=> (
    <div>
      <img
        src={item.image}
        alt={item.title}
      />
    </div>
))}
```

Comment: Thank you very much for your response. I forgot to add something while writing the question, but I was thinking what I forgot. I forgot to mention that I am using the map function. Forgive me. I'm already using the map function. However, unfortunately, I cannot access the images as I mentioned above.

Comment: can you share any codesandbox or online code ?

Comment: Hello. Thanks for your response. I managed to solve my end by using Image component instead of img tag. Now I can pull my image data from an array. Thanks again for your help. ^_^